Spotify API invalide client secret
I'm trying to make an api call for Spotify but it is not working right now. From Oauth2 i don't think we are supposed to pass the clinent secret but i have this error
(base) ivoryle@dyn234000 Ivoryle82.github.io % curl -X POST 
-H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" 
-d "client_id=b4c01840ec424a1aa275703fc29b8fac" 
-d "grant_type=authorization_code" 
-d "code=AQAjPlofVWr3-Z8eXgMCxA6lupNkqMixFECInJVP3GMbxnbteinhOaebmGE5g3JUUsjyuv06EY-BGa00y1L-uLMhOFr7jtUAAdryNhtzDVO6lzDdjswGDbtuPCZWzOS3g-WJcfICUbAox2Pv7F335aG18ONOvCMmBZ2l-vASnYbZo6yPiNY6bEICddEBarZQZ4pKFxe4yZnbJCJUMpHlffsdSJxtAsAQRdW_" 
-d "redirect_uri=http://localhost:3000/compatibility" 
https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token
{"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"Invalid client secret"}%
Anyone know why ?
I searched it up and it is a really bad practice to put your client secret up

You can get access token by cURL for Authorization Code flow.
You have to provide client secret.

You have to do two manual steps
#1 Get redirect URL string for Browser by node.js
get-url.js
const CLIENT_ID = "{your Client ID}"; // b4c01840ec424a1aa275703fc29b8fac
const PORT = 3000;  // your redirect PORT
const REDIRECT_URI = `http://localhost:${PORT}/callback`; // your redirect URI http://localhost:3000/compatibility
const SCOPES = 'ugc-image-upload playlist-modify-public playlist-modify-private'; // your scopes

// URL-encode the scope
const encodedScope = encodeURIComponent(SCOPES);

// Construct the authorization URL
const redirect_url = `https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=${CLIENT_ID}&scope=${encodedScope}&state=123456&redirect_uri=${REDIRECT_URI}&prompt=consent`;

// You can now use this URL to direct the user's browser for authentication
console.log(redirect_url);

Run it
node get-url.js

Result

Copy inside red rectangle to clipboard
#2 Paste it in the Browser end Enter to get the code

Get this long string, copy just code value

#3 Paste code for cURL
And put your client ID, Client Secret and redirect URI
curl -X POST https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token \
-d "grant_type=authorization_code&redirect_uri=REDIRECT_URI&code=CODE" \
-u CLIENT_ID:CLIENT_SECRET \
-H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

Result
You can get the access token by cURL

